# INTRO-LVL PROGRAMMER: Verify & Execute Guidance in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a non-CIS major taking an intro programming classes for a minor through my university. I've been able to successfully code most of the PHP files I need but have been getting hung up over how to perform two functions within the same document. Hopefully you can help.

Within the website, I want to be able to first use MySQL to check a table, called User (where a user is initially registered by the site) to verify that they are in fact registered and that the credentials they provided are correct, and then execute an query to add them to another table.

I've tried mysqli_multi_query to no avail and am just generally inexperienced and unsure of my options as far as functions go.

**I have included the code below but be aware that it is a mess as I've attempted several different things before I decided to get some help**

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    require_once("config.php");

    $GroupDesc = $_GET["GroupDesc"]; 
    $LeaderID = $_GET["LeaderID"];
    $URL = $_GET["URL"];
    $Email=$_GET["Email"];

    $con = mysqli_connect("$SERVER","$USERID","$DBPASSWORD","$DATABASE");

    $query2= "INSERT INTO FA15_1052_tuf02984.WebsiteGroups (ID, Description, LeaderID, URL, LeaderEmail) VALUES ('$GroupDesc', '$LeaderID', '$URL', '$Email');";

    /* Here I want to perform the first query or $query1 which checks if the 
    user exists in MySQL and the info submitted in form is same */

    $query1= "SELECT * from USER where LeaderID = '$ID' and Email = '$Email';";
    if ($status = mysqli_query($con, $query1)) {
        } else {
            print "Some of the data you provided didn't match our records. Please contact the webmaster.".mysqli_error($con)." <br>"; 
            $_SESSION["RegState"]= -11;
            $_SESSION["ErrorMsg"]= "Database insertion failed due to inconsistent data: ".mysqli_error($con);
            header("Location:../index.php");
            die();
        }

    /* How do I tell the file to move onto the next query, which is $query2?

    if ($query2) {
      $query = "INSERT INTO FA15_1052_tuf02984.WebsiteGroups (ID, Description, LeaderID, URL, LeaderEmail)
      VALUES ('$GroupDesc', '$LeaderUID', '$URL', '$Email');";
    }       */

        } else { 
            print "Membership update failed. Please contact webmaster.".mysqli_error($con)." <br>"; 
            $_SESSION["RegState"]= -11; // 0: Not Registered, 1: Register, -1: Error 
            $_SESSION["ErrorMsg"]= "Database Insert failed: ".mysqli_error($con);
            header("Location:../index.php");
            die();
        }
```

Comment: What is it `do $query2`?

Comment: My attempt at trying to make it execute the second function. I warned you that this code is a mess!

Comment: We don't need mess here. Read [mcve] and show us something that is not mess.

Comment: Thanks for that resource! I've updated the code to focus solely on my problem and added some comments for direction. Let me know if this is a satisfactory modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few points where your code can be rearranged to make the logic easier to follow. (Don't worry; this is just stuff that comes with experience.) I'll include some comments within the following code to explain what I've done.

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    require_once("config.php");

    $GroupDesc = $_GET["GroupDesc"]; 
    $LeaderID = $_GET["LeaderID"];
    $URL = $_GET["URL"];
    $Email=$_GET["Email"];

    // mysqli_connect is deprecated; the preferred syntax is
    $con = new mysqli("$SERVER","$USERID","$DBPASSWORD","$DATABASE");

    $query1= "SELECT * from USER where LeaderID = '$ID' and Email = '$Email';";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query1);

    // I personally prefer the following opening-brace style; I just find it
    //  easier to read. You can use the other style if you want; just do it 
    //  consistently.
    if ($result)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($row)
        {
            if (($row['ID'] != $LeaderID) or ($row['Email'] != $Email))
            {
                // Handle the error first, and exit immediately
                print "Some of the data you provided didn't match our records. Please contact the webmaster.".mysqli_error($con)." <br>"; 
                $_SESSION["RegState"]= -11;
                $_SESSION["ErrorMsg"]= "Database Insert failed due to inconsistent data: ".mysqli_error($con);
                header("Location:../index.php");
                die();
            }
            else
            {
                // If the query succeeded, fall through to the code that processes it
                $query = "INSERT INTO FA15_1052_tuf02984.WebsiteGroups (ID, Description, LeaderID, URL, LeaderEmail)
                             VALUES ('$GroupDesc', '$LeaderUID', '$URL', '$Email');";

                $status = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                if ($status)
                { 
                    // membership has been updated  
                    $_SESSION["RegState"]=9.5; // 0: Not Registered, 1: Register, -1: Error 
                    $message="This is confirmation that you the group you lead has been added to our database.
                        Your group's ID in our database is "$GID". Please keep this in your records as you will need it to make changes.
                        If this was done in error, please contact the webmaster at tuf02984webmaster@website.com";
                    $headers = 'From: tuf02984webmaster@example.com'."\r\n".
                        'Reply-To: tuf02984webmaster@example.com'. "\r\n".
                         'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
                    mail($Email, "You are a group leader!", $message, $headers);
                    header("Location:../index.php"); 
                    // die();
                    // You only use die() to return from an error state.
                    // Calling die() creates an entry in the server's error log file.
                    // For a successful completion, use
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // If we get here, then something has gone wrong which we haven't already handled
    print "Membership update failed. Please contact webmaster.".mysqli_error($con)." <br>"; 
    $_SESSION["RegState"]= -11; // 0: Not Registered, 1: Register, -1: Error 
    $_SESSION["ErrorMsg"]= "Database Insert failed: ".mysqli_error($con);
    header("Location:../index.php");
    die();

?>
```

The basic idiom is: Do something, handle the specific error, handle success, do something else, etc., and finally handle any errors that can come from multiple points. If anything is unclear, just ask and I'll edit into my answer.

I haven't covered prepared statements here. [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) are the preferred way to perform non-trivial queries; they help to resist [SQL injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) as well as simplify type-matching, quoting and escaping of special characters.

Comment: `if ($row['ID'] != $LeaderID) or ($row['Email'] != $Email)` it's syntax error

Comment: I just read through that saying "Ohhhh...." for a few minutes. That logic makes WAY more sense. So mysqli_function_assoc is fetching what row(s) that data is located? It seems that way. And then you would use that information to check against it... right?

Comment: Yes, [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) fetches a single row from the result set produced by the query.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. When I went to make the changes on my end, it seems like the code gets hung up on "    if ($result)" and I have no idea why. If I test a few lines further, Developer Tools on Google gives me a 500 Internal Service Error. Any insight?

Comment: Not sure. Add the statement `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the file, before `session_start();` and see what happens.

Comment: Nothing special showed up. Just a blank page. I did notice from the Developer Tools that it flashes "GET *link from form page and data entered* 500 (Internal Sever Error)". It's not supposed to be POST in this instance, right?

Comment: 'Fraid I'm not familiar with Google Dev Tools. Do you have access to your server's `error.log` file?

Comment: It's okay! I noticed a small error in the code. Extra variable in one of the query lines. Thanks SO much for your help- PHP is still new to me and I appreciate your willingness to advise.